# Python Extracting from xml request

Tags: python, xml, soap

im building a site(flask) and making using a payment api but its my first time using api and i have no clue how get the variables from xml

Here is the xml that return from request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="API_Library">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:gerarReferenciaMBResponse>
            <sucesso>true</sucesso>
            <entidade>82142</entidade>
            <referencia>000762738</referencia>
            <valor>5</valor>
            <estado>0</estado>
            <resposta>OK</resposta>
        </ns1:gerarReferenciaMBResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And my request look like this

```
import requests

    url = "https://sandbox.***.pt/****/api/api.php?wsdl=replica.*****.wsdl"

    payload = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="API_Library">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:gerarReferenciaMB>
         <valor>5</valor>
         <chave>****</chave>
         <id>1</id>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <admin_callback>0</admin_callback>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <token>0</token>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <campos_extra>
            <id>0</id>
            <valor>0</valor>
         </campos_extra>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <per_dup>0</per_dup>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <testa_pagamento>1</testa_pagamento>
      </api:gerarReferenciaMB>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'  
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

My question is how is suppose to me to get the " and " values to set variables.

Comment: The question is not clear - please explain in details

Comment: @balderman Hey, i get from the api request the <entidade> and  <referencia> and i need to sent it  to python variable

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to get it:

```
    for item in a.split("</entidade>"):
        if "<entidade>" in item:
            print(item[item.find("<entidade>") + len("<entidade>"):])

    for item in a.split("</referencia>"):
        if "<referencia>" in item:
            print(item[item.find("<referencia>") + len("<referencia>"):])
```

This will print whats between tags

Comment: Dont go in this way - you better do XML parsing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2915423

Answer (score 0):

Try the below - it will create a python dict that contains the data you are looking for

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="API_Library">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:gerarReferenciaMBResponse>
            <sucesso>true</sucesso>
            <entidade>82142</entidade>
            <referencia>000762738</referencia>
            <valor>5</valor>
            <estado>0</estado>
            <resposta>OK</resposta>
        </ns1:gerarReferenciaMBResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
elements = ['entidade','referencia']
data = {ele.tag: ele.text for ele in list(list(root)[0][0]) if ele.tag in elements}
print(data)
```

output

```
{'entidade': '82142', 'referencia': '000762738'}
```

Comment: `{ele.tag: ele.text for ele in root.iter() if ele.tag in elements}`